# Append addition String to SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I want to append a String to an ID that I pull from my database into a Cursor. I have a ListView with 2 item and I want the text to write Id+" some text". I use SimpleCursorAdapter and simple_list_item_2.

```
final Cursor data=myDb.vrniKorFaktor();
 if(data.getCount()==0) {
        Toast.makeText(KorFaktor.this, "Ni podatkov", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        while (data.moveToNext()){
            idFaktorja.add(data.getInt(0));
            String[] faktorji= new String[]{"_id","korfaktor" };
            int[] toViewId=new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, data, faktorji, toViewId );
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't in anyway relate to the question you are asking, I can't see any String pulled from the database. Please post a more proper code so we can see where and how to help you.

Comment: Have to tried a StringBuild then on that StringBuilder using the .append method?

Comment: Would basing the cursor on `SELECT _id ,_id || "mydata" AS mynewcolumn FROM shoplist` suit? This would result in 2 columns one just with the id, the other with the id and the string (assuming the string is constant).

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa The string is being pulled from the database and it's a basic SELECT statement. Or have i missed something?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MikeT I will try that and see how it goes :)

Comment: Other potential ways would be to build an array and use an array adapter, or to use a custom Cursor Adapter.

Comment: Another way could be to use a `MatrixCursor` which you can build and populate programmatically. e.g. `MatrixCursor mymxcursor = new MatrixCursor(columns_as_string_array);` and then use `mymxcursor(object)` to add rows. And then use this to feed the `SimpleCursorAdapter` (noting that YOU MUST have a column named _id). Not tried this personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have "_id","korfaktor" these two as your column name. You can use '||' operator to append some string to your _id. So your query is like below.

**Query**

```
select _id ||" hello" as _id , korfaktor from your_table_name
```

Note : " hello" you can replace the string your version.

Hope this works for you.